# How to manage SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError?

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js, pool

I have a seat reserve application with high traffic using Node.Js and **Sequelize** with Postgres. I configured pool connection like this:

```
"dialect": "postgres",
"logging": false,
"dialectOptions": {
  connectTimeout: 10000
},
"pool": {
  max: 100,
  min: 0,
  acquire: 60000,
  idle: 1 * 30000,
  createRetryIntervalMillis: 200,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 20000,
},
"retry": {
  max: 1, // Maximum retry 3 times
  backoffBase: 100, // Initial backoff duration in ms. Default: 100,
  backoffExponent: 1.5, // Exponent to increase backoff each try. Default: 1.1
},
```

**Problem**: When coming 101 concurrent request, The pool is full and accrued timeout.

**Error**:

```
ConnectionAcquireTimeoutError [SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError]: Operation timeout
    at ConnectionManager.getConnection (../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:204:15)
    at async ../node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:301:26
    at async PostgresQueryInterface.select (../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:407:12)
```

I saw different solutions and most of them suggest increasing the max pool. But this does not solve the problem.
The timeout problem is solved and new requests get correct response again, when the program is reset after the timeout. Otherwise, any other request will receive an error whenever it comes.

Some of my services include multiple read and write operations in the database in one transaction.

```
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction()
try{
   const ticket = await this.createTicket(travelTicketId, { transaction });
   ...
   await transaction.commit();
}
catch(error){
   await transaction.rollback();
}
```

Without using transaction, `ConnectionAcquireTimeoutError` error doesn't occurred But it may cause other internal errors that we have to rollback transaction.

**Question**:

1. How to handle transactions with open connections in pool?
2. Although closing the connection does not solve the problem, is closing the connection the right thing to do?
3. How can I make the program automatically exit from this deadlock state?